# Making a JQuery button act as a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Take this JQuery UI Button sample as a reference:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#splitbutton

Now, how would you implement that dropdown when click the small button?
My caution is mainly with the transformation .button() does to the actual button that messes the offset coordenates.

To sum it, I need opinions on how to correctly implement a dropdown on the click of a JQuery button that integrates with the current theme.

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: simply add the code to display your dropdown div in the click event

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image: I finally made it and looks like this]

I finally made it and looks like the picture above.
I blogged about it [here](http://www.instanceofanobject.com/2011/07/jquery-button-dropdown.html) and I'm also posting all the code bellow.
Please refer to the blog post for deeper explanation.

### CSS

```
<style type="text/css">

    .ItemActionButtons{}
    .ItemActionButtons .SaveExtraOptions
    {
        display: none; list-style-type: none; padding: 5px; margin: 0; border: 1px solid #DCDCDC; background-color: #fff; z-index: 999; position: absolute;
    }
    .ItemActionButtons .SaveExtraOptions li
    {
        padding: 5px 3px 5px 3px; margin: 0; width: 150px; border: 1px solid #fff;
    }
    .ItemActionButtons .SaveExtraOptions li:hover
    {
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: #DCDCDC;
    }
    .ItemActionButtons .SaveExtraOptions li a
    {
        text-transform: none;
    }
</style>
```

### HTML

```
<div class="ItemActionButtons">
    <div class="buttonset" style="float: right;">
        <input id="btnDelete" type="button" value="Delete" class="button" onclick="ItemActionButtons.onDeleteClick.apply(this)" />
        <input id="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel" class="button"onclick="ItemActionButtons.onCancelClick.apply(this)" />
    </div>  
    <div id="divSaveButton" class="buttonset" style="float: right;">
        <input id="btnSave" type="button" value="Save" class="button" onclick="ItemActionButtons.onSaveClick.apply(this)" />
        <input id="btnSaveExtra" type="button" class="button" value="+" onclick="ItemActionButtons.onSaveExtraClick.apply(this)" />

        <ul class="SaveExtraOptions ui-corner-bottom" id="btnSaveExtraOptions">
            <li onclick="$('#btnSaveExtraOptions').toggle(); ItemActionButtons.SaveAndNewClick.apply(this)">Save and New</li>
            <li onclick="$('#btnSaveExtraOptions').toggle(); ItemActionButtons.SaveAndCopyClick.apply(this)">Save and Copy</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).delegate('#btnSaveExtra', 'mouseleave', function () { setTimeout(function(){ if (!ItemActionButtons.isHoverMenu) { $('#btnSaveExtraOptions').hide(); }}, 100, 1) });
    $(document).delegate('#btnSaveExtraOptions', 'mouseenter', function () { ItemActionButtons.isHoverMenu = true; });
    $(document).delegate('#btnSaveExtraOptions', 'mouseleave', function () { $('#btnSaveExtraOptions').hide(); ItemActionButtons.isHoverMenu = false; });

    var $IsHoverExtraOptionsFlag = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".button").button();
        $(".buttonset").buttonset();
        $('#btnSaveExtra').button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-plusthick" } });
        $('#btnSaveExtraOptions li').addClass('ui-corner-all ui-widget');
        $('#btnSaveExtraOptions li').hover(
            function () { $(this).addClass('ui-state-default'); },
            function () { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-default'); }
        );
        $('#btnSaveExtraOptions li').mousedown(function () { $(this).addClass('ui-state-active'); });
        $('#btnSaveExtraOptions li').mouseup(function () { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-active'); });
    });

    var ItemActionButtons = {
        isHoverMenu: false,

        AllowDelete: function (value) { value ? $("#btnDelete").show() : $("#btnDelete").hide() },
        AllowCancel: function (value) { value ? $("#btnCancel").show() : $("#btnCancel").hide(); },
        AllowSave: function (value) { value ? $("#btnSave").show() : $("#btnSave").hide() },
        AllowSaveExtra: function (value) { value ? $("#btnSaveExtra").show() : $("#btnSaveExtra").hide() },

        onDeleteClick: function () { },
        onCancelClick: function () { },
        onSaveClick: function () { },
        onSaveExtraClick: function () {
            $('#btnSaveExtraOptions').toggle();

            var btnLeft = $('#divSaveButton').offset().left;
            var btnTop = $('#divSaveButton').offset().top + $('#divSaveButton').outerHeight(); // +$('#divSaveButton').css('padding');
            var btnWidth = $('#divSaveButton').outerWidth();
            $('#btnSaveExtraOptions').css('left', btnLeft).css('top', btnTop);
        },
        SaveAndNewClick: function () { },
        SaveAndCopyClick: function () { }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

A pluggin is also available to do this.

[jQuery DropDown Button](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, drowdowns should always appear 'over' other content, not push it down, so absolute positioning is perfect for that. Basically add a wrapper div with `position: relative` around the button and the dropdown menu (which will have `position:absolute; display:none`), and toggle the dropdown visibility on click. The absolute positioning of the dropdown shouldn't be affected by other children of the wrapper div, such as the button, so it will appear exactly where you tell it to in the CSS.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I know positioning and how to achieve the basics of what I'm asking, my problem is with the transformations the .button() does to the actual <input type="button" /> control that messes with the offset coordenates and I have no guarantee that the returned coordenates will work correctly if I change the theme.

Comment: Ah ok, well then is it possible to set the width and height of the button **before** the `.button()` transformation to match the dimensions **after**? Unless by 'coordinates' you mean something other than what I'm thinking.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container"> 
    <span class="arrow">&or;</span> <span class="default">Choose your option...</span>
    <input type="hidden" value="" class="mehidden"/>
    <ul class="selectBox">
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.arrow
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 26px;
    left: 208px;
    line-height: 26px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 26px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.selectBox
{
    border: 1px solid #1F1F1F;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    display:none;
    top: 25px;
}

#container
{
    position:relative
}

.toggler
{
    overflow:visible;
}

.default
{
    border: 1px solid #1f1f1f;
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
    padding:3px;
    position:absolute
}

.selectBox li:hover
{
    background:#ddd
}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('.arrow').click(function() {
    $('.selectBox').slideToggle(200).css('borderTop', 'none');
    $('.selectBox li').click(function() {
        $('.mehidden').val($(this).text());
        $('.default').text($(this).text());
        $('.selectBox').slideUp(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: @AlexCode may my solution is not exact what you want. but i post this to help to make your own dropdown.

Comment: Thanks mate. My concerns were more with the layout integration with jQuery and making sure it would blend correctly on the themes than actually how to implement the basic dropdown functionality.
Have a look at my solution post.