# jQuery UI dialog buttons with drop down list of actions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a normal jQuery dialog (as shown in the first image) and 3 possible actions and 3 buttons (as this is a confirmation for user action).

I need to add 4th button (4th possible action) which I think it is too much. So, I thought about adding a drop down button for the dialog (as shown in the second image).

Is that even possible?

Many thanks for your input.

First image:

[image: First image]

Second image:

[image: Second image]

Comment: Yes it is possible to add some extra markup in the dialog then use CSS to re-arrange/position the buttons and the "special" button.

Comment: @SalmanA Do you have some example of code? Thanks.

Comment: @AndyJones What to try if I don't know if it is possible? I don't like to waste anybody time. I Google it first but don't found anything. There can be a solution to add the dropdown button inside the dialog but my question is if it is possible to have the dropdown on the footer of the dialog.

Comment: Here is an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546010/making-a-jquery-button-act-as-a-dropdown).

Comment: @Jasen I saw this before asking the question. Not much help. It's talking about making a drop down button but not on the dialog footer. I'm using jQuery UI Dialogs. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @SalmanA Thanks for heads up! Any idea about the z-index on the drop down button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Your idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21008724/87015) is right. However, the z-index issue is in fact an overflow issue. To fix this:

- Add a class to dialog so that it is easier to customize
- Set overflow property on the dialog to a suitable value

**Code and Demo:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialogSuccess").dialog({
    buttons: [
      { "text": "Option 1", "class": "btn btn-primary", "click": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
      { "text": "Option 2", "class": "btn btn-success", "click": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
    ],
    create: function() {
      var menuHTML = "";
      menuHTML += "<div class='btn-group'>";
      menuHTML += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>Action <span class='caret'></span></button>";
      menuHTML += "<ul class='dropdown-menu pull-right' role='menu'>";
      menuHTML += "<li><a href='#'>Action 1</a></li>";
      menuHTML += "<li><a href='#'>Action 2</a></li>";
      menuHTML += "</ul>";
      menuHTML += "</div>";
      $(this).closest(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-dialog-buttonset").append(menuHTML);
    },
    dialogClass: "overflow-fix",
    width: "auto"
  });
});
```

```css
@import url("https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css");
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css");

.overflow-fix {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Note: I am not  sure what is the recommeded order of including jQuery UI and Bootstrap -->

<div id="dialogSuccess" title="Action was successful">
  <p>What do you want to do next?</p>
</div>
```

**Screeshot:**

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks! That's the reason I love Stackoverflow! I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**I finally did it but have an issue with z-index on dialog footer.**

Any help with ***showing the button drop down over the dialog*** will be appreciated. Thanks.

Here is what I need:

```
var dialogButtons = jQuery('#dialogSuccess').parent().find('.ui-dialog-buttonset');

dialogButtons.append('<div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu"><li><a href="#">Action</a></li><li><a href="#">Another action</a></li></ul></div>');
```

See working solution:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/loginet/xh3D2/2/